# What is exactly a stream in C language?

Tags: c

I can't understand the meaning of "stream" in C language. Is it an abstraction ( just a name describe many operations)? Is it an object (monitor, keyboard, file on hard drive) which a program exchange data with it ? Or it 's a memory space in the RAM holding temporarly the exchanged data ?.
Thinks for help.

Comment: Streams are an abstraction. You don't have to know how they work, they just do, it really isn't important. What you do have to know is *how they behave*, i.e. what all the functions that operate on streams do.

Comment: i understand that but im curious to know how it work on the machine level

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you are right i  didn't explain it very well and i didn't pecised the question but you can understand it like this : what are exactly a stream ? what is it's relation with  the FILE structure ? how fopen function exactly works ?

Comment: A `FILE*` represents a (handle to a) stream. `fopen` works in an _implementation defined_ manner, `fopen` works differently on every platform. On linux with glibc it calls posix function [`open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) that calls the [system call `open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and allocates memory for `FILE*` virtual table - on windows we don't know what it does. Each [implementation of the C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations) has it's own `fopen` function that works differently.

Comment: @KamilCuk You gave a good idea how fopen works but my principle  question is what is a " stream"?

Comment: @john Your answer is the most convincing one. So the stream is not a thing, it is a many operations ensure the flow of data between the program and the object which concerning with the exchange of data. But any stream is manipulated and controlled with a FILE structure which predefined in <stdio.h> right ? So we manipulate the streams only through pointers of FILE* type. right ?

Comment: Yes, and the FILE type is deliberately *opaque*. You're not supposed to look inside to see how it works, because how it works will vary from one implementation to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stream is an abstraction of an I/O channel.  It can map to a physical device such as a terminal or tape drive or a printer, or it can map to a file in a file system, or a network socket, or something else completely.  How that mapping is accomplished is not exposed to you, the programmer.

From the perspective of your code, a stream is simply a source (input stream) or sink (output stream) of characters (text stream) or bytes (binary stream).  Streams are managed through `FILE` objects and the `stdio` routines.

As far as your code is concerned, all streams behave the same way, regardless of what they are mapped to.  It's a uniform interface to operations that can have wildly different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Stream is just the sequence of data available over the time. It is distinct from the file for example because you cant set the position. Examples: data coming/going through the RS232, USB, Ethernet, IP newworks etc etc.

> but my questions are what are exactly a stream on the machine level

Nothing special. Machine level does not know anything about the streams.

> What is exactly a stream in C language?

Same - C language does not know anything about the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Stream is a a sequence of data bytes of unknown length, which flows to the input or from the output of the program .

Answer (score -1):

In C when we use the term stream, we indicate any input source or output destination.

Some example may be:

- stdin (standard input which is the keyboard by default)
- stdout (standard output which by default is the screen)
- stderr (standard error which is the screen by default)

Functions such as printf, scanf, gets, puts and getchar, are functions that have the keyboard as input stream and the screen as output stream.

But we can create streams to files to! 
The stdio.h library supports two types of files, text files and binary files. Within a text file, the bytes represent characters, which makes it possible for a human to read what the file contains. By contrast, in a binary file, bytes do not necessarily represent characters. In summary, text files have two things that binary files do not: Text files are divided into lines, and each line ends with one or two special characters. The code obviously depends on the operating system. In addition, text files can contain the file terminator (END OF FILE).

Comment: i already know this. but my questions are what are exactly a stream on the machine level ?

Comment: `a stream on the machine level ? ` There are no streams on machine level. Stream is an abstraction in C language. On machine level there are interrupts - there is system interrupt that allows to communicate with the kernel (or there is no kernel).

Comment: @KamilCuk So a stream is just a name which simplifies the meaning of many operations ? a stream it is not a thing communicating with a program neither a memory space wich hold  temporarly some data?

Comment: `which simplifies many opérations` It's just a word, it's an abstraction. You don't drive to work with a "4-wheeled machine" you drive with a "car". You use the word "car" to faster communicate what you have in mind - an abstraction. Maybe peek at [definition of stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.2p1) in the C standard.

Comment: `a stream it is not a thing communicating` Well, on each system you "communicate" with hardware differently. On systems with a monolithic kernel you first talk to kernel, then it communicates with the hardware. But not necessarily. There are many layers of abstraction on the way. Still a `FILE*` pointers _points_ to some memory and uses that memory. Maybe from the other more practical side see an actual [implementation of `fopen` in glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/fileops.c#L212).

Answer (score -1):

Streams are specific to the running program as well. Let me explain this further.

When you run a program through the terminal (Unix-like/Windows) what essentially it does is:

1. The terminal forks into a child process and runs your specified program (./name_of_program).
2. All the printf statements are given to stdout of the parent process which forked. Same for, scanf statements but now to stdin of the parent process that forked.
3. The operating system handles the characteristics of the streams, i.e. how many bytes can be streamed to stdin/out at once. Generally in Unix it is 4096 bytes. (Hint: Use pipes to overcome this issue).
4. There are three types of streams in C or any Programming language, Buffered, Line-buffered and Unbuffered. (Hint: use delay() function between each printf() call to know what this mean)

Now, the read and write access to files is handled by other service of the OS which is file descriptor. They are positive integers used by OS to keep track of the opened files and ports (like Serial Port).